# AngularJS - Loading my directives suddenly not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

http://danieboy.github.io/

I've worked on this webpage on and off for a while now and after a 2 month break from it I went on and wanted to optimize it with the help of Dareboost. I made some minor changes like optimizing my pictures and changed the raw.github.com to rawgit.com in the references after looking up the error and finding a thread here on stackoverflow (<3). Sadly...now my AngularJS stopped loading my pages like it did before and I'm at a loss as to what I should change. I followed the stacktraces on google chrome (F12 -> Console) and fixed all the errors I could see there but now there are none and yet the Angular parts aren't loading properly.

Any help would be apprechiated.

Comment: looks like you need are missing css for `content-current` class which would be `.content-current{display: block !important;}`

Comment: does it helpful to you?

Comment: @pankajparkar Sorry for the slow answer, this didn't seem to change anything sadly. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: @pankajparkar Actually a lot of things changed after it finally updated and I refered to the correct CSS. But it looks very...weird...right now xD

Comment: it looks like site is working now..but the css is broken..

Comment: Yeah I'm terrible at CSS. I might make a new post on just that part. Would you mind posting your answer so that I can approve it? :)   @pankajparkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need are missing `css` for `content-current` class which is responsible for showing active tab.

**CSS**

```
.content-current{
    display: block !important;
}
```