# My CSS broke when I fixed another issue, how do I fix my header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVeHk.jpg

Picture 1 code:

**main.css**

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1D2130;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 60%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 60%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 60%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 60%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 60%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.15, rgb(200,225,245)),
    color-stop(0.58, rgb(240,240,240))
    );
}

header {
    width: 950px;
    height: 60px;
}

header img{
    float: left;
    left: -185px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

header h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 85px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    font-weight: thin;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Impact, Times, arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-width: 650px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 650px;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #000;
}

a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #d5000d;
}

header {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #303030;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #aaa;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

code, pre {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Terminal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

code {
    padding: 0 3px;
}

pre {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
pre code {
    padding: 0;
}

ul, ol, dl {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* COMMON STYLES */

table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

td {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

form {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f2f2f2;

}


/* GENERAL ELEMENT TYPE STYLES */

h1 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
}

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #303030;
}

h3 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #d5000d;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #303030;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #303030;
}

h6 {
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #303030;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p a {
    font-weight: 400;
}

blockquote {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    border-left: 10px solid #e9e9e9;
}

ul li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: disc inside;
}

ol li {
    padding-left: 3px;
    list-style: decimal inside;
}

dl dd {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #aaa;
}

footer a {
    color: #666;
}

/* MISC */
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: '.';
}

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}

.type-csharp .highlight .s { color: #A31515 }



html {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}


body {
    margin: 0;
}


article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
    display: inline-block; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

[hidden],
template {
    display: none;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}


dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}


h1 {
    margin: 0.67em 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

mark {
    color: #000;
    background: #ff0;
}


small {
    font-size: 80%;
}


sub,
sup {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}


img {
    border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}


figure {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}


hr {
    height: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    margin: 0; /* 3 */
    font: inherit; /* 2 */
    color: inherit; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
    overflow: visible;
}

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}


fieldset {
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

legend {
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    border: 0; /* 1 */
}


textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}


optgroup {
    font-weight: bold;
}


table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}

/* LAYOUT STYLES */
body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #666;
    background: #fafafa url(../pictures/body-bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
}

a {
    color: #2879d0;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2268b2;
}

header {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    background: #2e7bcf url(../pictures/header-bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #275da1;
}

header h1 {
    width: 540px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

header h2 {
    width: 540px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #9ddcff;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content-wrapper {
    padding-top: 30px;
    border-top: solid 1px #fff;
}

#main-content {
    float: left;
    width: 690px;
}

#main-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

aside#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 504px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    background: transparent url(../pictures/sidebar-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

a.button {
    width: 134px;
    height: 58px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-left: 68px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #fff;
}
a.button small {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
}
header a.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent url(../pictures/github-button.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
aside a.button {
    display: block;
    width: 138px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    background: transparent url(../pictures/download-button.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

code, pre {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Lucida Console", Terminal, monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #222;
}

code {
    padding: 0 3px;
    background-color: #f2f8fc;
    border: solid 1px #dbe7f3;
}

pre {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}
pre code {
    padding: 0;
    color: #2879d0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
}

ul, ol, dl {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* COMMON STYLES */

hr {
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

th {
    font-weight: 500;
}

td {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

form {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f2f2f2;

}


/* GENERAL ELEMENT TYPE STYLES */

#main-content h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 6px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

#main-content h1:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -0.9em;
    color: #9ddcff;
    content: "/";
}

#main-content h2 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 4px;
}
#main-content h2:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    content: "//";
    color: #9ddcff;
}

#main-content h3 {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 3px;
}

#main-content h3:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -2em;
    content: "///";
    color: #9ddcff;
}

#main-content h4 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 3px;
}

h4:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -2.8em;
    content: "////";
    color: #9ddcff;
}

#main-content h5 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 3px;
}
h5:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -3.2em;
    content: "/////";
    color: #9ddcff;
}

#main-content h6 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #474747;
    text-indent: 3px;
}
h6:before {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    margin-left: -3.7em;
    content: "//////";
    color: #9ddcff;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p a {
    font-weight: 400;
}

blockquote {
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    border-left: 10px solid #e9e9e9;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc inside;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal inside;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

dl dd {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #aaa;
    background: transparent url('../pictures/hr.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

footer a {
    color: #666;
}
footer a:hover {
    color: #444;
}

/* MISC */
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: '.';
}

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}

/* #Media Queries
================================================== */

/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { }

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .inner {
        width: 740px;
    }
    header h1, header h2 {
        width: 340px;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
    header h2 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    #main-content {
        width: 490px;
    }
    #main-content h1:before,
    #main-content h2:before,
    #main-content h3:before,
    #main-content h4:before,
    #main-content h5:before,
    #main-content h6:before {
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        content: none;
    }
}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .inner {
        width: 93%;
    }
    header {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
    header .inner {
        position: relative;
    }
    header h1, header h2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    header h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    header a.button {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1;
        color: #2879d0;
        text-align: center;
        background: #9ddcff none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    header a.button small {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    #main-content,
    aside#sidebar {
        float: none;
        width: 100% ! important;
    }
    aside#sidebar {
        min-height: 0;
        padding: 20px 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-image: none;
        border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
    }
    aside#sidebar a.button {
        display: none;
    }
    #main-content h1:before,
    #main-content h2:before,
    #main-content h3:before,
    #main-content h4:before,
    #main-content h5:before,
    #main-content h6:before {
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        content: none;
    }
}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) { }

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) { }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPQad.jpg

Picture 2 code:

**Main.css**

```
    body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1D2130;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,225,245) 15%, rgb(240,240,240) 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.15, rgb(200,225,245)),
    color-stop(0.58, rgb(240,240,240))
    );
}

#main-body {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 60%;
    border-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    width: 950px;
    height: 60px;
}

header img{
    float: left;
    left: -185px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

header h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 85px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    font-weight: thin;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Impact, Times, arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-width: 650px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 650px;
}

#meter {
margin-top: 0;
float: left;
width: 72%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-left: 30px;
}

#gauge {
position: absolute;
width: 259px;
opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
}

#right-arrow {
    width: 192px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#hot-arrow {
    width: 41px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 114px;
    display: none;
}

#cold-arrow {
    width: 77px;
    margin-top: 129px;
    margin-left: 117px;
    display: none;
}

#outputSpace {
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 320px;
    color: #1C2130;
    opacity: .5;
    min-width: 942px;
    height: 75px;
}

.output-message {
    display: none;
    width: 720px;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#buttonArea {
    margin-top: -35px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    min-width: 700px;
}

#numberField {
    margin: 25px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
}

#Button1 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #c1300d;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.content-current 
{
    display: block !important;
}
```

**index.html (pretty much the same for both pages)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="developerBlog">
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/pygment_trac.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/print.css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/tabs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="semantic-ui@*" data-semver="0.9.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/css/semantic.min.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script data-require="semantic-ui@*" data-semver="0.9.6" src="https://rawgit.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/0.9.6/build/packaged/javascript/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="myDirectives.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title>Danieboy.GitHub.io by Dan Andersson</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="BlogController as blog">

  <svg class="hidden">
    <defs>
      <path id="tabshape" d="M80,60C34,53.5,64.417,0,0,0v60H80z"></path>
    </defs>
  </svg>

    <header>
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Danieboy.GitHub.io</h1>
        <h2>Developer blog</h2>
        <p class="support">Your browser does not support <strong>flexbox</strong>! <br />Please view this demo with a <strong>modern browser</strong>.</p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div class="inner clearfix">
        <section id="main-content">



          <div class="tabs tabs-style-shape">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#section-shape-1">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <span>Start</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#section-shape-2">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <span>Resume</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#section-shape-3">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <span>My Projects</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#section-shape-4">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <span>Reviews</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#section-shape-5">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 80 60" preserveAspectRatio="none"><use xlink:href="#tabshape"></use></svg>
                    <span>Contact</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="content-wrap">
              <section id="section-shape-1">
                <start></start>
              </section>

              <section id="section-shape-2">
                <resume></resume>
              </section>

              <section id="section-shape-3">
                <myprojects></myprojects>
              </section>

              <section id="section-shape-4">
                <reviews></reviews>
              </section>

              <section id="section-shape-5">
                <contact></contact>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script src="javascripts/cbpFWTabs.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
        new CBPFWTabs( el );
      });

    })();
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

Previous post:

[AngularJS - Loading my directives suddenly not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571937/angularjs-loading-my-directives-suddenly-not-working)

Website:

http://danieboy.github.io/

http://danieboy.github.io/bmi-calculator/index.html

---

So when I fixed so that my tabs would properly show the the information to the corresponding tab thanks to the help of @pankajparkar by adding:

```
.content-current{display: block !important;}
```

To my css file - the header broke. I would say that I am terrible at CSS so that's why I'm asking - I am more of a back-end programmer so sorry if this is a very simple question but I'd like to learn more about this. The website got quite a few CSS files so I'm not going to post them all here. But as you probably know you can go on the website in Google Chrome and press F12 -> Sources to see them all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the code and a jsfiddle. if you fix your site the question wont have any value for others

Comment: @atmd Actually I didn't even think about that. I will do that and add pictures before making changes to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://danieboy.github.io/ you have fixed height and width for your header (row 30 in main.css). Just remove that and it will work for you.

On http://danieboy.github.io/bmi-calculator/index.html you have to set both width and height to auto for your header and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

As your styling is terrible :P

just do this to header and it's fixed for you..

```
header {
   width: 950px;
   height: 150px;
}
```

or a best solution set height to auto like

```
header {
   width: 950px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Moreover if you want to align your header in center

```
header {
   width: 950px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and one Last thing :D 
apply this for your header bottom text ;)

```
header h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 38px;
  font-family: Impact, Times, arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The header h2 help, thank you. I used that + @Kamelkent solution and set both width and height to auto.